# Which CMS should I use when I hand a website over to my non-techie friend?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I'm designing a simple website for a friend - four static pages to advertise a yoga retreat she is running. I have a couple of requirements:

1. My time is short; I want to quickly build a theme template.
2. She has no technical skills; she wants to log in to the backend and update page content.

Working for myself, a static site builder such as `nanoc` or `jekyll` would be ideal: I can build a `template.html` with room for some content, then update content files, rebuild the site and redeploy. As a bonus, the whole site could be hosted free on GitHub pages. **This satisfies requirement (1) but not requirement (2).**

I've also considered Wordpress, because I've got plenty of experience running WP sites and developing custom themes. **This satisfies requirement (2) but not (1).** There is simply too much development overhead building a WP theme - it is not straightforward to modify the markup structure of all those template files, and there are plenty of snags involving ugly page titles or "Comments are disabled" strings which need to be removed.

It shouldn't be this difficult. I want a site engine which has a simple `template.html` file for easy re-theming, and an accessible backend for content changes. Bonus points if free hosting is available somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perch - http://www.grabaperch.com - is made for this sort of thing, though it's not free (£).

Could you hack a site together using tumblr pages?

Comment: Perch looks like it might be nice. I love the simple customizable theme of Tumblr, so I'm going to see if I can hack something together using that for now.

Answer (score 1):

What about Google Sites? Dead simple.

Comment: it does. Not sure about JS but you can have your own HTML. I use it to write my stuff with Markdown and then copy and paste the html into Sites. Like it a lot. Very easy and works like any other editor. Or do you mean html for templates? That I'm not sure about. Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to .NET i think you should look at n2cms.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress using a premium theme bought in any of the many sites offering quite nice themes for a reasonable price (60 USD). Then, you just change the logo and ready to go.

Since I'm not a web designer myself, this is what I´ve done myself for my sites and I´m quite happy with the results